# Compile error on if else condition in trigger

Tags: oracle, hibernate

```
 create or replace
  TRIGGER TRG_DEPT_ID BEFORE INSERT ON DEPT FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DEPT cd WHERE cd.st_num = :new.ST_NUMBER AND cd.td_NUMBER = :new.TD_NUMBER)
  THEN
        SELECT SEQ_DEPT_ID.NEXTVAL INTO :new.ID FROM dual;        
  ELSE
        SELECT ID FROM DEPT INTO :new.ID WHERE cd.st_num = :new.ST_NUMBER AND cd.td_NUMBER = :new.TD_NUMBER;
  END IF;   
  END ;
```

I am trying to check for duplicate entry. If not exists, then I will create a new Id from sequence. Else I will put the same id.
  And the `SaveOrUpdate(dept);` will do the remaining.

But it gave me compile error.`Error(8,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored.`

### UPDATE:

When I tried the following query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_DEPT_ID 
BEFORE INSERT ON DEPT FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     BEGIN
          SELECT ID 
          INTO :NEW.ID 
          FROM DEPT 
          WHERE cd.st_num = :NEW.ST_NUMBER 
          AND cd.td_NUMBER = :NEW.TD_NUMBER;     
     EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
          SELECT SEQ_DEPT_ID.NEXTVAL INTO :new.ID FROM dual;        
     END;
END;
```

Getting the error:

`ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`

How to handle this error?

Comment: Well, then your query is returning more than one row.  Either your constraints are wrong, or if more than one row is allowed, you need to change the logic.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: Yes.. if I put rownum to resolve the above issue, then a unique key violation will occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply code your trigger like this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_DEPT_ID 
BEFORE INSERT ON DEPT FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     BEGIN
          SELECT ID 
          INTO :NEW.ID 
          FROM DEPT 
          WHERE cd.st_num = :NEW.ST_NUMBER 
          AND cd.td_NUMBER = :NEW.TD_NUMBER
          AND rownum = 1;    --Use rownum = 1 to avoid selecting too many rows.
     EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
          SELECT SEQ_DEPT_ID.NEXTVAL INTO :new.ID FROM dual;
          --:NEW.id = seq_dept_id.nextval; -- Or you can use this if you are using 11g or higher versions.
     END;
END;
```

**Edited:**

You can modify your trigger code as below if duplicate entries are there in your table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_DEPT_ID 
BEFORE INSERT ON DEPT FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
     l_id DEPT.id%type;
BEGIN
     BEGIN
          SELECT ID 
          INTO l_id
          FROM DEPT 
          WHERE cd.st_num = :NEW.ST_NUMBER 
          AND cd.td_NUMBER = :NEW.TD_NUMBER
          AND ROWNUM = 1;    --Use rownum = 1 to avoid selecting too many rows.
          IF l_id IS NOT NULL THEN --If same st_number and td_number exists.
               raise_application_error( -20001, 'Duplicate entry.');
          END IF;
     EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
          SELECT SEQ_DEPT_ID.NEXTVAL INTO :new.ID FROM dual;
          --:NEW.id = seq_dept_id.nextval; -- Or you can use this if you are using 11g or higher versions.
     END;
END;
```

Comment: Tried this. This time  `ORA-00001: unique constraint (DEPT_PK) violated`

Comment: @tailorBird, Which are the primary key columns in dept table.?

Comment: Only the column `ID`.

Comment: @tailorBird, So it sounds like your max(id) in dept table is beyond the value of SEQ_DEPT_ID.nextval. So you need to compare both and recreate your sequence.

Comment: Sequence LAST_NUMBER is 161 and table has only one row with id = 141.

Comment: @tailorBird, Okay, this might be because of your trigger. If you are trying to insert a record with same st_number and td_number the trigger will assign the same id `141` for id. Hence the error.

Comment: So how can I modify the trigger?

Comment: @tailorBird, What you really want if the same st_number and td_number are in the table dept? You want an exception message or anything else?

Comment: I need to assign the id (taken from the table) to `:new.ID` if the record exists.. else assign a new id to `:new.ID` from sequence(a fresh entry.)

Comment: @tailorBird, This is what We've done at first(In your updated question). In this case You'll get the same error as before ,`ORA-00001: unique constraint (DEPT_PK) violated`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `rownum` in the where section :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_DEPT_ID 
BEFORE INSERT ON DEPT FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    BEGIN
       SELECT ID 
       INTO :NEW.ID 
       FROM DEPT 
       WHERE cd.st_num = :NEW.ST_NUMBER 
       AND cd.td_NUMBER = :NEW.TD_NUMBER
       AND ROWNUM =1;   
 EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
      SELECT SEQ_DEPT_ID.NEXTVAL INTO :new.ID FROM dual;        
 END;
END;
```

That will make the query to just return 1 row in case cd.st_num and cd.td_NUMBER are repeated in more than one row.

On the other hand, if you need to detect that there are more than one row for these two columns , you can catch the exception `TOO_MANY_ROWS` in the exceptions section

```
     EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
      SELECT SEQ_DEPT_ID.NEXTVAL INTO :new.ID FROM dual;        
     when TOO_MANY_ROWS then
         -- your logic to do when there are too many rows     
 END;
```